# find number of teams from a file

Tags: bash, cut, uniq

I have started learning bash very recently and have to find the number of teams from a file, the file can be downloaded from [this link](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/mlb_players.csv).

Below is a sample

[image]

I understand that I have to use cut and uniq but I can't figure out how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Say `teamsfile` is file containing data from which you want total count of teams, then

#### 1. using `cut` and `uniq`

```
tail -n +2 teamsfile | cut -d "," -f2 | uniq | wc -l
```

- **tail -n +2 teamsfile**  - prints file but doesn't prints first line (which in your case are labels of the values)
- **cut -d "," -f2** - cut 2nd field seprated by a comma (acting as delimiter)
- **uniq**        - show only unique values. (Can also use `sort -u`)
- **wc -l**          - print number of lines in output

Alternatively you can use `sed` and `awk`. they are very useful in such tasks.

#### 2. Using `grep` to avoid printing Ist line.

```
cat teamsfile | grep -v "Team" | cut -d "," -f2 | sort -u | wc -l
```

- **grep -v** - negates the search for string " Team"

Comment: You don't need to cat then grep - grep will take a a file as an input

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Please edit the answer as I don't know how to do it directly with `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use awk to print all the team and then find the count.

```
grep -v "Team" teamsfile | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -u | wc -l
```

This one liner will give you the number of teams.

**Explanation** ::

grep  :  will pick all the lines containing 'Team' keyword in it.

awk   :  it breaks the lines on the basis of a 'comma' and print the 2nd column of it, that contains the team names.

sort -u : it will first sort all the team names alphabetically and then keeps only unique records.

wc -l :  it will provide the number of lines on which data is present, in above case the number of unique team names.

Comment: Might be nice to step through this - for those folk who don't get what it does. Also... you don't need to cat and grep. Its cat abuse.  You can grep -o teamsfile -v .... I think

Comment: Thankyou @JourneymanGeek for giving tips, so that I can help others in a better way.